# How can I keep bare root blackberries viable for 8 days?

Tags: growth, storage, blackberry, growing-medium

I ordered some bare root blackberries for myself and a friend. They left the nursery last Friday, but my friend won't be able to pick them up and plant them until Saturday.

What can I do to ensure the plants are still viable on Saturday, presumably 8 or 9 days after they were dug up, or do I even need to worry?

These are just the stem and roots; they weren't packed in a growing medium of any kind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, bare root plants are supplied with wrapped roots - that might be burlap or fabric or some plastic, so hopefully that's what they've done. When you get them, soak the roots in a bucket of water for at least 2 hours, then plant out. If its a good supplier, they may come with instructions, and these often tell you how long to stand them in water for.

UPDATE: Sorry, I hadn't quite grasped the situation, I thought you meant you couldn't collect them from wherever they were waiting. As you've got them already, if you mean, by wrapped in plastic, each one is contained within a plastic bag from top to bottom, they should be fine left outside in a shady spot. If only the roots are wrapped, then can you find somewhere to heel them into the ground? That just means digging a bit of a hole and burying the roots in it temporarily until they can be planted permanently -its often done if the weather isn't right for planting when the plants are delivered. Best done in a shady spot.

Comment: Yes, it came wrapped in plastic. I took out my half and followed the provided instructions. What I'm asking is how to store the remaining plants for the rest of the week until my friend can plant them. Do I need to keep the roots moist or anything?

Comment: @Philip - see updated answer